# Is it a good idea to lazy load GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager

In an attempt to improve initial load time on a web app i am working on, I wanted to run the GTM scripts after my application is loaded.

1. I wanted to know if this is a good idea?
2. If i do this, what are the possible side effects?

Comment: can someone post the piece of code how this script will load dynamically/lazzily?

Answer (score 7):

**TL;dr**

it seems that it is fine to lazy load GTM.

**long version**

Generally I would run scripts in the way that the creator recommends to run it.

I assume you want to lazy load GTM because of GDPR?

they accept GDPR -> you load GTM.
At least, for me that is the only reason to lazy load GTM and that is the reason I am on this very page.

If you look at the loading of GTM you can see they already kind of lazy load it. In detail, they load it **async**. That means the page loads while GTM loads as well. This can obviously lead to the effect that the page, if it is very short, loads before GTM is loaded.

See their recommended way to include GTM:

```
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
      new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-MYID');
```

notice `j.async=true`

so it should be fine to lazy load GTM as it already is used to be a bit lazy loaded.

I was thinking maybe "page view" triggers / tags could be an issue. But it seems, that is not the case, at least in the few tests I ran. Pageview will fire even if you wrap the GTM loading function into a `setTimeout(function(){}, 5000);` I still get the page views fired.
[image]

as I was asked to provide an example code of lazy loading GTM I will add it below:

this makes use of jquery, so make sure jquery is loaded before this script exectues:

```
     function loadGTM(){

var my_GTM_id = 'GTM-ASDASDAS'; // BE SURE TO UPDATE THIS TO MATCH UR ID
//you can add checks here to see if GDPR got accepted if you want...
(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
        w[l] = w[l] || [];
        w[l].push({
          'gtm.start':
              new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
        });
        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
        j.async = true;
        j.src =
            'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
      })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', my_GTM_id);
    }
    $( document ).ready(loadGTM);
```

notice: I haven't tested this.

Comment: Can you post a code how can I load this script lazzily?

Answer (score 1):

1. Is a matter of opinion, so probably off-topic
2. If users abort before you app is fully loaded you will not track them. If this is actually bad depends on your circumstances; at least you should verify that loading your app does not take too long (since you will have no way to catch aborted loads with your tracking tags).

So it's a trade-off between slightly faster page loads and potential data loss. Ideally you would do an A/B test to see if your relevant KPIs actually improve when you defer the events to the page load, if they don't then the question is moot in any case.